# Yii2 - Add header color and prevent override in CSS

Tags: css, yii2

I have a theme for my project. From the diagram, I want to change the color of **Download** to red, but the parent **callout-info** overrides it.

[image: css theme]

and the css of the theme

```css
.callout code,
.callout .highlight {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.callout.callout-danger {
  border-color: #c23321;
}
.callout.callout-warning {
  border-color: #c87f0a;
}
.callout.callout-info {
  border-color: #0097bc;
}
.callout.callout-success {
  border-color: #00733e;
}
```

**and my view**

```html
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="callout callout-info">
     <h4><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'You must have to follow the following instruction at the time of importing data'); ?></h4>
     <ol>
      <li><b><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'The field with red color are the required field cannot be blank.'); ?></b></li>
      <li><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'The file must be CSV format.'); ?></li>
     </ol>
     <h5><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Download the sample format of Excel sheet.'); ?> <b><?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Download'), ['download-file', 'id' => 'SSF']) ?></b></h5>
    </div><!--./callout-->
   </div><!--./col-->
  </div><!--./row-->
```

I have extracted my concern out here, from the css above
[image: css restyle]

So, how do I make **Download** to be red in color without the parent

> border-color

**callout-info** overriding the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by saying *without the parent callout-info overriding the color*? If I misunderstood, please correct me.

Your given style doesn't work on a link since there is no `a` tag in there (you can confirm this by temporarily removing your `<style>`). You can override color in at least 2 ways:

-- Inserting in `<style>` new rule:

```
.callout.callout-info a {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

-- Inserting third parameter in `Html::a`:

```
Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Download'), ['download-file', 'id' => 'SSF'], ['style' => 'color: #ff0000']);
```

---

P.S. I also see you added `css3` tag, so this one will work too (assuming you have a compiler):

```
.callout.callout-info {
    border-color: #c87f0a;

    & a {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
}
```